# Factory Reverse design pattern discussion

Tags: php, refactoring, factory-pattern

I used to use factory method as a creational design pattern, but now I got stucked in the situation which is reversing the problem.
The normal behavior to create the factory pattern. I am facing the following: I got different inputs for the same data object. I create a function that set the data to the object based on the passed data like the following:

```
public function __construct(array|Ad $data){
    match(getType($data)){
        'array' => $this->setFromArray($data),
        default => $this->setFromSnapAdModel($data)
    };
}
```

Is that looking right or not? Is that pattern that I face in my code is looking like reversing the factory creational method?

Comment: I’m unclear on your problem. Does this not work? Or are you asking our opinion on this?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am asking for opinion, and If there is patter for my problem or not ?